# Change UIDocumentBrowserViewController Create Document button text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uidocumentbrowservc

I have a document based iOS app that uses `UIDocumentBrowserViewController`. The app allows document creation, so the file browser that appears when the app launches contains the standard button with the large + symbol and default text *Create Document*, like in the image below.

Is it possible to change the default text, so that it's more specific to my app? For example, like in the Numbers app where the text is *Create Spreadsheet* rather than *Create Document*.

I could not find documentation related to this question.

[image: Document Browser Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

iOS 13 added the `localizedCreateDocumentActionTitle` property to allow you to change the title of the button.

```
/// Title of the Create Document button (default: "Create Document”).
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
open var localizedCreateDocumentActionTitle: String
```